# PostgreSQL 14 json Input Cannot Insert For Each Attribute To Each Column

Tags: json, postgresql, stored-procedures

When I try to insert json input to my stored procedure it shows below error< i Googled a lot and couldn't find any solution, I am Little confused about the type conversion In Postgres

```
--Call
do $$
    declare d TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
    v_json JSON;
    begin
        select now() INTO d;
        CALL sp_insert_or_update_branch('{"code":"TestCode", "name":"testName"}'::jsonb, v_json);
    end;
$$; 

--SP
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_insert_or_update_branch(jsnBranch JSONB, jsnSqlRes OUT JSON) AS $$
    DECLARE
        objSpOutRes TYP_SP_OUT_RES;
        objFnCheckRes TYP_FN_CHECK_RES;
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO organization.tbl_branch
        (fk_company_id, vhr_branch_code, vhr_branch_name, ars_product_ids)
        VALUES(1, jsnBranch->>code, jsnBranch->>name, '{1}');
        
        --COMMIT;
        objSpOutRes.binSqlPk := 1::BIGINT;
        objSpOutRes.sinSqlCustomStatus := 1::SMALLINT;
        objSpOutRes.strSqlCustomStatusCode := 'SUCCESS';
        objSpOutRes.strSqlCustomMessage := 'Branch Saved';

        SELECT * FROM  fn_convert_type_out_object_to_out_json(objSpOutRes) INTO jsnSqlRes;
        RAISE NOTICE 'jsnSqlRes: %', jsnSqlRes;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
--Error
ERROR:  column "code" does not exist
LINE 3:      VALUES(1, jsnBranch->>code, jsnBranch->>name, '{1}')
                                   ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO organization.tbl_branch
                    (fk_company_id, vhr_branch_code, vhr_branch_name, ars_product_ids)
                    VALUES(1, jsnBranch->>code, jsnBranch->>name, '{1}')
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function sp_insert_or_update_branch(jsonb) line 6 at SQL statement
SQL statement "CALL sp_insert_or_update_branch('{"code":"TestCode", "name":"testName"}'::jsonb, v_json)"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at CALL
SQL state: 42703
```

Comment: The right hand side of the `->>` operator requires a string value `code` is a column reference, `'code'` would be a string value: `jsnBranch->>'code'`

Comment: Also How can i use other datatypes like date,int,big int

Comment: INSERT INTO organization.tbl_branch
     (fk_company_id, vhr_branch_code, vhr_branch_name, ars_product_ids, dtm_created, int_sys_action_id)
     VALUES(jsnBranch->>companyId::BIGINT, jsnBranch->>'code'::VARCHAR, jsnBranch->>'name'::VARCHAR, '{1}', jsnBranch->>current_dete::TIMESTAMP, jsnBranch->>action_id::INT);

Comment: above code how can i insert @a_horse_with_no_name